# Add Multiple fragments in a activity asynchronously after the app is loaded

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am new to both Xamarin and android app development, I have a requiremet as below

I have the mainactivity in which i do have multiple frame layouts, Now i need to load different fragments on these layouts one on each, So I would like to make this happen once the app is loaded because all these fragments depend on external data which would hit an external server to get the data... So i dont want to put the fragments statically into my axml file and make the app waiting untill all fragments are loaded.

So just want to open the app...may be show some headers and then all fragments should be loaded asynchronously.(not sure if we have any background threading concepts here which would run and then once completed which would update the view)

Please let me know if you need any more details...Is this doable in any way..... Please help me with this....

-Karthik

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MvvmCross you could do something like the example of Cheesebaron:
https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MvxFragmentsAndHamburger/blob/master/MvxFragmentsAndHamburger/Droid/Views/HomeView.cs

Depending on the request you show the fragment in the correctframe:

```
bool IMvxFragmentHost.Show(MvxViewModelRequest request, Bundle bundle)
        {
            if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(FirstViewModel))
            {
                ShowFragment(Resource.Id.content_frame, bundle);
                return true;
            }
}
```

In my own app i've also made some adjustments to the custom presenter to make it easier for me to have no initial viewmodel but just an activity hosting the fragments:

```
public override void Show (MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            var fragmentHost = Activity as IMvxFragmentHost;
            if (fragmentHost != null) {
                var bundle = new Bundle ();
                var serializedRequest = Serializer.Serializer.SerializeObject (request);
                bundle.PutString (ViewModelRequestBundleKey, serializedRequest);
                fragmentHost.Show (request, bundle);
            }
            else
            {
                var bundle = new Bundle();
                var serializedRequest = Serializer.Serializer.SerializeObject(request);
                bundle.PutString(ViewModelRequestBundleKey, serializedRequest);

                var intentFor = new Intent (Activity.ApplicationContext, typeof(MainActivity));
                intentFor.PutExtra ("request", bundle);
                base.Show(intentFor);
            }
        }
```

Now you could add something like this to your activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Bundle request = Intent.GetBundleExtra ("request");
            if (request != null) {
                var deserializedRequest = Serializer.Serializer.DeserializeObject<MvxViewModelRequest>(request.GetString(CustomFragmentsPresenter.ViewModelRequestBundleKey));
                Show (deserializedRequest, request);
            }
        }
```

And finally this to show the fragment in the frame:

```
public void ShowFragment(MvxViewModelRequest request, int contentId, Bundle bundle = null, bool addToBackStack = false)
        {
            MvxFragment fragment = null;

            IMvxViewsContainer viewContainer = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
            Type viewType = viewContainer.GetViewType(request.ViewModelType);

            Fragment currentContentFragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(contentId);
            if (currentContentFragment != null && currentContentFragment.GetType () == viewType && (request.ParameterValues == null || (request.ParameterValues != null && request.ParameterValues.Count == 0))) {
                drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
                return;
            }
            fragment = (MvxFragment)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);

            var loaderService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
            var viewModel = loaderService.LoadViewModel(request, null);
            fragment.ViewModel = viewModel;

            var contentManager = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            contentManager.Replace(contentId, fragment);
            if(addToBackStack)
                contentManager.AddToBackStack(fragment.GetType().Name);
            contentManager.Commit();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, I am not aware of what MVVMcross is, anyway I will look into this option once....actually I was thinking if there would be some way or event kind of thing which would convert the fragment load event to Async...

Comment: For more information on MVVMCross you can take a look at: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross